# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ without using Fourier Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can we prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ without using Fourier series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The most common way to do this is attributed to Euler. It does still require Maclaurin series, however.

Consider the Maclaurin polynomial for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$:

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \cdots$$

However, note that this is a polynomial $p(x)$ with zeroes $\{\pm k\pi\;|\;k \in \Bbb N\}$, and for which $p(0) = 1$. These two properties mean that

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \left(1 + \frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\cdots$$

And by multiplying adjacent terms,

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{9\pi^2}\right)\cdots$$

Equating the $x^2$ terms in the Maclaurin polynomial and its factored form yields

$$-\frac{x^2}{3!} = -x^2\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2} + \frac{1}{4\pi^2} + \frac{1}{9\pi^2} + \cdots\right)$$

And multiplying both sides by $-\frac{pi^2}{x^2}$ gives us

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots$$

Comment: The modern objections to this argument should probably be mentioned. One cannot say "an infinite series is just like a polynomial" until convergence issues have been resolved. In this case, Taylor series arguments give us that $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$ converges to $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ as $n \to \infty$. But to use the argument above, one must justify that $g_n(x) = \prod_{k=1}^n 1 - \frac{x^2}{k^2 \pi^2}$ *also* converges to $f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. One method would be to apply Weierstrass's factorization theorem (since $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is holomorphic).

Comment: Right, the objections are valid, and though Euler's method of proof here was eventually vindicated, it should be noted that infinite series can't necessarily be treated in the same way as finite polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are hereby awarded this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem.

Comment: You are hereby awarded a downvote for posting link-only answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2) already contains proofs that does not rely   on Fourier series. 
Also 
Robin Chapman has a [collection of proofs](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) on his homepage.